# SVG initial zoom not working correctly (Matrix Transform)

Tags: javascript, css, svg, matrix-transform

I've recreated the SVG map from this [article](https://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/pan-and-zoom/)

The **first** time you zoom out with the "-" it zooms in, then kind-off correctly itself and happily works both ways!

I cant figure out why its behaving like this, being no expert in matrix transformations ?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/sajrashid/pen/gOzgYdm)

[working Codepen](https://codepen.io/sajrashid/pen/gOzgYdm) with accepted answer fix applied

**HTML**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 250 150" id="map-svg">
<g id="matrix-group" transform="matrix(0.6400000000000001 0 0 0.6400000000000001 44.99999999999998 26.99999999999999)">        
    <path id="WA" class="territory" d="m 38.3, 168.2 c -1.9,-0.6 -3.6,-1.1 -3.8,-1.3 -0.2,-0.2 0.8,-2.5 2.25,-5.2 1.4,-2.7 2.6,-5.5 2.6,-6.2 0,-0.8 -1.8,-4.25 -4,-7.7 -2.2,-3.5 -4,-7.1 -4,-8.1 l 0,-1.8 -6.4,-10.3 -6.4,-10.3 1.8,0 -7,-14.8 0.2,-7.3 c 0.1,-4 0.1,-8.9 0.1,-10.9 l -0.1,-3.5 5.5,-6 c 3,-3.3 5.5,-6.3 5.5,-6.7 0,-0.4 0.9,-0.8 1.9,-0.8 l 1.9,0 9.8,-6.1 13.8,-2.2 4.1,-2.6 8.4,-15 -1.2,-3 3.3,-5 1.8,1.1 4,-2.5 0,-3.1 4.6,-4.3 8.5,0 3.4,3.8 c 1.9,2.1 3.4,4.3 3.4,5 l 0,1.3 2.5,-0.6 L 97.5,33.2 c 0,38.3 0,77 0,113.8 l -4.6,1.6 -4.5,2.2 -2.3,5.6 -1.6,0.5 c -0.9,0.3 -4.8,1 -8.6,1.6 l -7,1.1 -8.2,4.9 -8.2,4.9 -5.3,0 c -2.9,0 -6.9,-0.5 -8.8,-1.1 z"></path>
    <path id="QLD" class="territory" d="m 200.3,123.9 c -11.8,-0.7 -14.8,-0.8 -22.8,-1.3 0,-8.5 0,-21 0,-21 l -16,0 c 0,0 0,-39.3 0,-60 l 6,3.5 5.2,3.5 4.4,0 6,-9.8 3.4,-24.6 2.8,-5.7 c 1.6,-3.1 3.3,-6 3.9,-6.3 l 1,-0.6 1.8,4.3 c 1,2.4 2.2,6.6 2.6,9.3 0.4,2.8 1.2,7.1 1.7,9.8 l 1,4.8 4.8,0 3.2,5 2.8,11 c 1.5,6.1 3.3,11.7 4,12.5 0.6,0.8 3.4,2.9 6.2,4.6 l 5,3.2 5,10 3.8,1 1.2,5.2 11.2,14.8 1.2,7.1 c 0.7,3.9 1.5,8.7 1.9,10.8 l 0.6,3.7 -1.3,5.1 -4.6,-1.1 -1.3,1.6 c -1.6,2 -3.7,2 -4.4,0.1 l -0.6,-1.5 -2.4,0 c -1.3,0 -4.3,0.7 -6.7,1.5 -2.3,0.8 -5.4,1.4 -6.9,1.3 -1.4,-0.1 -12.3,-0.7 -24.1,-1.4 z"></path>    
    <path id="VIC" class="territory" d="m 219.5,177.3 0.8,1 c 0,0.6 2.3,2.7 5,4.8 l 5,3.8 -11.4,3.4 -5.7,5.4 -6.9,-3.7 -2.8,1.4 c -1.5,0.8 -3,1.5 -3.3,1.6 -0.3,0.1 -2.3,-0.9 -4.5,-2.2 c -2.2,-1.3 -6.3,-3.1 -9,-4 l -5,-1.6 -2.3,-2 -2.1,-2.1 c 0,-9 0,-17.9 0,-26.6 l 3.9,-1.3 3.1,0 1.6,3.4 1.9,0.5 2.4,0.5 1.5,0.9 4.7,6 3.2,3.9 c 3.2,0.9 6.5,1.7 9.2,2.4 3,0.8 4.7,0.9 6.2,1 l 2.9,2.6"></path>
    <path id="NSW" class="territory" d="m 220.5,176.4 -2.4,-2.7 -2.4,-1.5 c -2.1,-0.3 -6.2,-1.1 -9.1,-1.8 l -5.4,-1.4 -8.2,-10.4 -2.8,-0.7 -2.8,-0.7 -1,-1.9 -1,-1.9 -3.9,0 -4,1.5 0,-30.9 c 5.8,0.4 22.5,1.4 25.3,1.6 l 23.5,1.4 4.8,-1.2 c 4.6,-1.1 5.7,-2.1 8.3,-2 0,0 0.9,2.3 1.9,2.8 1.1,0.5 2.5,0.1 3.7,-0.3 1.1,-0.4 2,-2 3.1,-1.8 l 2.8,0.5 -1.3,5.1 c -0.7,2.7 -2.1,7.5 -2.9,10.9 -1.8,8.3 -3.1,11.6 -5.3,13.4 l -1.8,1.5 -4.1,12.5 c -2.2,6.9 -4.2,13.5 -4.4,14.7 l -0.3,2.2 -5.3,-4 -4.4,-4.2"></path>
    <path id="SA" class="territory" d="m 176,181 -6.8,-9.4 0.7,-3.7 0.7,-3.7 -5.6,-6 -2.2,0.8 0.7,-7.8 -1.1,0 c -1.1,0 -2.2,1.1 -4.6,4.5 l -1.4,2 1,-4.8 c 0.6,-2.7 0.8,-5 0.6,-5.3 -0.8,-0.8 -6.1,2.5 -7.9,4.8 -0.9,1.2 -1.9,2 -2.1,1.8 -0.2,-0.3 -1.6,-2.6 -3.1,-5.2 l -2.7,-4.7 -11.4,-2.6 -19.2,0.2 -5.8,2.6 C 102.7,146.2 99,147.2 99,147 l 0,-44 77,0 z"></path>    
    <g id="NT" class="territory">
        <path d="m 99,33 3.9,0.4 c 2,0.2 4.4,-0.5 5.5,-1 l 1.9,-1 0,-2.5 0,-2.5 -2,0 0,-4 1.9,-1.7 c 1,-0.9 1.7,-2 1.5,-2.4 l -0.5,-0.7 6.8,-4.2 11.5,-1.4 0.8,-2.4 -5.6,-3 1.7,0 c 0.9,0 2,0.4 2.3,1 0.3,0.6 1.2,0.9 1.8,0.8 0.6,-0.1 3.4,0.8 6.2,2.1 l 5,2.4 7.5,0 0,3.7 -4.2,4 1.2,3.2 -3,5.8 17,11.2 0,60.8 -61,0 z"></path>
        <path d="m 115,8.7 -2.8,-0.4 0.8,-2.4 4.2,0 c 2.3,0 4.2,0.2 4.2,0.5 0,0.8 -2.3,3 -2.9,2.8 -0.3,-0 -1.8,-0.3 -3.4,-0.6 z"></path>
    </g>
    <g id="TAS" class="territory">
        <path d="m 202.7,223.9 -2.7,-3.6 -0.1,-3.4 c -0.1,-1.9 -0.4,-3.7 -0.8,-4.1 -0.4,-0.4 -0.7,-1.8 -0.7,-3.1 l 0,-2.3 1,0 c 0.6,0 2.4,0.7 4.2,1.6 l 3.1,1.6 9.6,-1.2 0,7.2 -3.4,5.8 -2.6,-1 -1.7,3 c -0.9,1.6 -2,3 -2.4,3 -0.4,0 -1.9,-1.6 -3.4,-3.6 z"></path>
    </g>
    <g id="ACT" class="territory">
        <path stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#ffffff" d="m 222,165.7 0.1,2.8 0.4,1.4 1,1 0.4,-0.9 0.2,2.9 2.6,1.6 1,-2.2 0,-3.6 c 0,0 -0.3,-0.5 -0.6,-1.1 0.8,-0.3 1.2,0.1 1.2,0.1 l 0.1,-3.4 1.5,-2 2.4,0.3 0.5,-1 -2.7,-1.3 c 0,0 -0.7,-1.8 -1.8,-2.4 -1.6,1.1 -4,2 -5.2,3.9 -0.4,0.7 -0.5,2.3 -0.5,2.3 z"></path>
    </g>
</g>

<circle cx="25" cy="25" r="21" fill="white" opacity="0.75"></circle>
<path class="button" onclick="pan(0, 25)" d="M25 5 l6 10 a20 35 0 0 0 -12 0z"></path>
<path class="button" onclick="pan(25, 0)" d="M5 25 l10 -6 a35 20 0 0 0 0 12z"></path>
<path class="button" onclick="pan(0,-25)" d="M25 45 l6 -10 a20, 35 0 0,1 -12,0z"></path>
<path class="button" onclick="pan(-25, 0)" d="M45 25 l-10 -6 a35 20 0 0 1 0 12z"></path>

<circle class="compass" cx="25" cy="25" r="10"></circle>
<circle class="button" cx="25" cy="20.5" r="4" onclick="zoom(0.8)"></circle>
<circle class="button" cx="25" cy="29.5" r="4" onclick="zoom(1.25)"></circle>

<rect class="plus-minus" x="23" y="20" width="4" height="1"></rect>
<rect class="plus-minus" x="23" y="29" width="4" height="1"></rect>
<rect class="plus-minus" x="24.5" y="27.5" width="1" height="4"></rect>
```

**CSS**

```
    .territory {
        fill: #a9a9a9;
    }
    .territory:hover {
        fill: #22aa44;
    }
    .compass {
        fill: #fff;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 1;
    }
    .button {
        fill: #225EA8;
        stroke: #0C2C84;
        stroke-width: 0.5;
        stroke-miterlimit:6;
        stroke-linecap: round;
    }
    .button:hover {
        stroke-width: 1;
    }
    .plus-minus {
        fill: #fff;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
var transformMatrix = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0];
var svg = document.getElementById("map-svg");
var viewbox = svg.getAttributeNS(null, "viewBox").split(" ");
var centerX = parseFloat(viewbox[2]) / 2;
var centerY = parseFloat(viewbox[3]) / 2;
var matrixGroup = svg.getElementById("matrix-group");

function pan(dx, dy) {
  transformMatrix[4] += dx;
  transformMatrix[5] += dy;
  var newMatrix = "matrix(" + transformMatrix.join(" ") + ")";
  matrixGroup.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", newMatrix);
}

function zoom(scale) {
  for (var i = 0; i < transformMatrix.length; i++) {
    transformMatrix[i] *= scale;
  }

  transformMatrix[4] += (1 - scale) * centerX;
  transformMatrix[5] += (1 - scale) * centerY;

  var newMatrix = "matrix(" + transformMatrix.join(" ") + ")";
  matrixGroup.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", newMatrix);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to initialize the components of `transformMatrix` based on the `transform` specified in the HTML.

```
var transformMatrix = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0];
// :
var matrixGroup = svg.getElementById("matrix-group");

var initialMatrix = matrixGroup.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix;
transformMatrix = [ initialMatrix.a, initialMatrix.b, initialMatrix.c, initialMatrix.d, initialMatrix.e, initialMatrix.f ]; 

// :
```